# Presenting a Text Stream in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

i need to present a running text stream in my apps, i got the running text from my server and i can see it using NSLog that the stream is running. The text is change and have a new line every second.
Since i'm newbie in iOS i already made a research and there are couples that i still confuse :

1.Between UITableView and UIScrollView, which one you recommended regarding the performance?
2.What is the right library to use?is it llike NSStream or i just present it to my UITable?

Will appreciate if you can have a snippet code or tutorial for this.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have time to write the code, as it's not simple.

You will want to create a UITextView and append the string to the text view as you recieve new content.

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can use all UIScrollView operations on it, including scrolling down to the bottom as new content is added. This is the best way to have good performance, as UIScrollView and UITextView are both tightly integrated into the graphics hardware on the device.

If the text is really big (hundreds of megabytes) then you should also delete old text from the top of the text view as you add new text to the end.

Just use the code you have now, but instead of NSLog(), append it to the UITextView.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the feedback, after trying with uitableview and uitextview i decided to use uitextview because its much simpler with my condition, i do test benchmark for over 1 hours and no issue with performance.And i use NSMutableString since i need a new line is above, not below.

Comment: @user2373192 the UITextField has a property "storage" which is an NSTextStorage. This is a subclass of NSMutableString which is designed specifically for a text view, and modifying the text storage directly gives much better performance than modifying an NSMutableString.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, `UITableView` would be ideal choice, since it's well optimized to reuse its cells. If you use scroll view, 3600 lines (that's 1 hour log) will probably end up with 3600 text views (or labels),   while for table view, it would always be the number of rows visible on the screen.

For data model, I think you can just use a big array, which is continuously fetched with data from the server, possibly truncated when it gets too big (I mean deleting the very old lines).

Remember the rule of optimization: get it working first before optimizing it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a UITextView with a single massive string will be faster and use less RAM than a UITableView with a big array. It will not draw the entire string, it will only draw the substring that has changed with each insertion.

Comment: Hmm I don't think RAM is a big problem here, given that 1 MILLION characters cost only 1 or 2MB. Both `UITableView` and `UITextView` draw only visible parts of the text, so I don't think performance is a big problem either. `UITableView` is nicer if the log is line-by-line (similar to `NSLog`), but is not an option if the log is continuous, i.e. no line breaks.

Comment: I have a log that uses UITableView in my app, and I don't recommend it. The problem is it doesn't handle text wrapping by default, and if you implement proper text wrapping it will be extremely difficult to maintain good performance. If I was going to write my log view again, I'd use UITextView.